# Вызов класса из DLL во время ран тайма

Tags: c++

у меня есть класс

//Header:

```
#pragma once
#include "Headers/Test.h"

class RE_API Test : public A
{
public:
    void B() override;
};

RE_API void Create();
```

//Cpp:

```
#include "ExampleTest.h"
#include <iostream>

void Test::B()
{
    std::cout << "Its work";
}

void Create()
{
    Test b;
    b.B();
}
```

Эта единица трансляции билдится как .dll

Я пытаюсь вызвать функцию `Create()` из этого dll в самом уже .exe файле

```
    auto lib = LoadLibrary(L"assets/scripts/ExampleApp.dll");

    typedef void (*FNPTR)();
    FNPTR myfunc = (FNPTR)GetProcAddress(lib, "Create");

    myfunc();
```

Но при выполнении программы получаю исключение *Вызвано исключение по адресу*. Правильно ли я пытаюсь вызвать функцию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы имена функций в модуле при импорте были ровно такими, как написаны, их в файле .h окружают в общем случае такими вот "скобками" (иначе в C++ реальные имена получают ряд префиксов).

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" 
{
#endif /* _cplusplus */

RE_API void Create();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif /* _cplusplus */
```

Ну там у Вас классы, так что явно C++, достаточно `extern "C" { ...  }`

А вообще-то после `GetProcAddress` проверяйте `myfunc` на `NULL`.

Comment: Да, спасибо, это работает. Хотел бы еще уточнить, а можно как-то вызвать конструктор класса без что-то типа "фабричной функции", как у меня?

Comment: Проще говоря, как вызвать конструктор для класса :) И будет ли после вызван автоматически деструктор?

Comment: @justdo  Для динамического подключения делают обычно `void *Create() ;` и `void Destroy(void *handle);` Получаем `void* handle=Create()`, а во все функции передаем handle. Просто "пробиться" к функциям класса, в т.ч. к деструктору через С(а не C++) интерфейс не так просто. В вызывающей функции какую-нибудь простую "автоматизацию" на автоуказателях, чтобы вызвать `Destroy` при выходе из блока. В простейшем случае для `handle` можно использовать адрес объекта, созданного через new(). А Вам точно нужна динамическая загрузка?

Comment: Да, я делаю скрипты, которые потом подключаются к основному проекту во время ран тайма

Comment: А можно как-то инициализировать метод `Create` неявно? То есть, определить все методы класса, а сам метод `Create` как-то неявно, а потом так же получить к нему доступ?

Comment: Попробовал, вроде сооружается конструкция, если сделать базовый класс с нужными виртуальными функциями, а в dll создавать объект производного класса

Comment: То есть, если я создам базовый полностью виртуальным, и переопределю все в дочернем, тогда должно работать? А как тогда потом вызвать переопределенный класс?

Comment: Что-то не форматируется тут... {
    auto lib = LoadLibrary(L"plugin.dll");
    typedef Base* (*FNPTR)();
    FNPTR myfunc = (FNPTR)GetProcAddress(lib, "Create");
    std::unique_ptr<Base> d(myfunc());
    d->f();
    } '''

Comment: то есть, `(FNPTR)GetProcAddress(lib, "Create");` это уже сам метод класса?

Comment: Нет, в dll, прямо в cpp пишете `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void* Create()
{
 return new Derived();
}` Base и Derived - классы. Первый в общем заголовке, второй опять-таки прямо в cpp dll

Comment: А есть возможность абстрагироваться от вызова `Create` в dll? И вызвать неявно, не объявив в cpp

Comment: Или вызвать в cpp с абстрактным классом?

Comment: `Create` создает конкретный класс, вроде оно в dll должно быть, так что я не очень понимаю вопрос. А у класса `Base` никакого cpp нет, только заголовок. Можно, наверное, написать какой-то "конструктор", который подгрузит нужную dll и вызовет её `Create`. Но я что-то уже запутался, что Вам может потребоваться, так что экспериментируйте...

Comment: Я наверное уже сам запутался) Изначально я хотел понять как можно вызвать метод `Create` где был конструктор, потом стало интресно как можно вызвать этот метод неявно, то есть, не определив его в самом .dll, но возможно можно как-то создать в Base, добавив cpp файл